# Can we call Windows API functions in VBScript?

Tags: winapi, vbscript

I have the below code which finds a window and presses an 'OK' button in it.

I want to run this using standalone VBScript. Can this be done?

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
    If ie.Busy Then
        DoEvents
        hWND = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Message from webpage")
        If hWND <> 0 Then childHWND = FindWindowEx(hWND, ByVal 0&, "Button", "OK")
        If childHWND <> 0 Then SendMessage childHWND, BM_CLICK, 0, 0
    End If
Wend
```

Comment: VBScript does not support calling the Windows API. Your only option is to write a COM DLL that can be instantiated using `CreateObject()`.

Comment: Thank you fo the response, I was little bit aware of this but I have found the link where they have run it from vbs...I didnt get it completely, may be you can explain it. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/48f022dd-f62d-437e-be0e-b502c8f4cd94/accessing-win32-api-in-vb-scriptvbs-files?forum=isvvba

Comment: This is asking the wrong question. The question you should be asking is: How do I automate a UI? The answer to that question is: Use UI Automation. UI Automation is exposed as a COM interface.

Comment: @IInspectable - 100% agree on the principle, but unfortunately AFAIK UI Automation doesn't support COM automation so you can't use it from VBScript, which is a pity. It should. Maybe someone has written a wrapper? Not aware of any